# Format a file using VB Script

Tags: vbscript

Below is the file,

```
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST1)         TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(1000)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST2)               TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(5000)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST3)            TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(5000)
```

I need to format the above file as below, using VB Script

```
QUEUE(TEST1) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(1000)
QUEUE(TEST2) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(5000)
QUEUE(TEST3) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(5000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RegExp for the parts you are interested in:

```
  Dim reX  : Set reX  = New RegExp
  reX.Global  = True
  reX.Pattern = "\w+\(\w+\)"
  Dim sAll : sAll     = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\in.txt").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reX.Execute(sAll)
  Dim nMT
  For nMT = 0 To oMTS.Count - 1 Step 4
      WScript.Echo Join(Array(oMTS(nMT + 0), oMTS(nMT + 1), oMTS(nMT + 2), oMTS(nMT + 3)))
  Next
```

output:

```
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST1)         TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(1000)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST2)               TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(5000)
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(TEST3)            TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             MAXDEPTH(5000)

QUEUE(TEST1) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(1000)
QUEUE(TEST2) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(5000)
QUEUE(TEST3) TYPE(QLOCAL) CURDEPTH(0) MAXDEPTH(5000)
```

Comment: How to make it to write to a file instead of WScript.Echo .?